# Regex why does negative lookahead not work when there are two groups here

Tags: java, javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

when I tried this regex

```
\"(\S\S+)\"(?!;c)
```

on this string **"MM:";d** it comes as matched as I wanted

and on this string **"MM:";c** it comes as not matched as desired.

But when I add a second group, by moving the semicolon inside that group and making it optional using |

```
\"(\S\S+)\"(;|)(?!c)
```

for this string **"MM:";c** it comes as matched when I expected it to not like before.

I tried this on Java and then on Javascript using Regex tool debuggex:

[This link contains a snippet of the above](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XGh4BL04UTw9QUbt)

What am I doing wrong?

note the | is so it is not necessary to have a semicolon.Also in the examples I put c, it is just a substitute in the example for a word, that's why I am using negative lookahead.

After following Holgers response of using Possessive Quantifiers,

```
\"(\S\S+)\";?+(?!c)
```

it worked,  [here is a link to it on RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/wh42n)

Comment: You appear to have "half an OR statement" `(;|)`there - is that deliberate? It seems to mean to me "either a semicolon, or nothing". So the match would be correct?

Comment: I was using that to make the semicolon optional

Comment: It's best to use a question mark for that: `;?`.  It means exactly the same thing, but it adds less clutter, and you'll get far fewer comments asking if that's what you really meant. ;)

Comment: Any reasons you do not simply use `^"(\S+)";?[^c]$`?

Comment: this was the simplified version that I came up with after debugging to find out what was causing the bug. I need the semicolon captured as a group as I will expanding it in the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don’t want to make the semicolon optional in the sense of regular expression. An optional semicolon implies that the matcher is allowed to try both, matching with or without it. So even if the semicolon is there the matcher can ignore it creating an empty match for the group letting the lookahead succeed.

But you want to consume the semicolon if it’s there, so it is not allowed to be used to satisfy the negative look-ahead. With Java’s regex engine that’s pretty easy: use `;?+`

This is called a “possessive quantifier”. Like with the `?` the semicolon doesn’t need to be there but *if* it’s there it must match and cannot be ignored. So the regex engine has no alternatives any more.

So the entire pattern looks like `\"(\S\S+)\";?+(?!c)` or `\"(\S\S+)\"(;?+)(?!c)` if you need the semicolon in a group.

Comment: but I need the semi-colon to be optional, and there lies the problem as I didn't realise that regex will do anything to get a match. I have now removed the negative lookahead and made it a group, then after the match, I check the matched group to see if the c word is there

Comment: Please try to understand: with that possessive quantifier the semicolon *is* optional, but the regex is not allowed to “do anything to get a match” anymore. It’s exactly what you want (or at least what you described)

Comment: when I plugin your formulas into Debuggex Demo, it comes as "nothing to repeat".

Comment: Well, I referred to Java’s regex engine as your question was tagged with `Java`. Not every engine supports Possessive Quantifiers.

Comment: In `JavaScript` you can emulate Possessive Quantifiers (or Atomic Groups) using look-ahead and back-references: `(?=(;?))\1` is the equivalent to `;?+` but you have to care to adapt the back-reference when introducing more groups before that term.

Comment: Thanks I tried your Java code in an online Java Regex Tester and it worked here are it is http://fiddle.re/wh42n

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the regex will do what it can to find a match; since your expression said the semicolon could be optional, it found that it could match the entire expression (since if the semicolon is not consumed by the first group, it becomes a "no-match" for the negative lookahead.  This has to do with the recursive way that regex works: it keeps trying to find a match...

In other words, the process goes like this:

```
MM:" - matched
(;|) - try semicolon? matched
(?!c) - oops - negative lookahead fails. No match. Go back
(;|)  - try nothing. We still have ';c' left to match
(?!c) - negative lookahead not matched. We have a match
```

An update (based on your comment). The following code may work better:

```
\"(\S\S+)\"(;|)((?!c)|(?!;c))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gYMkYq9kER7aR356)

Comment: it seems to be consuming the semicolon in the second group as in Java when I was printing out the groups the semicolon appears in group 2 sometimes

Comment: It will consume the semicolon if doing so causes an over all match. But it will not do so if that means the negative lookahead would then be triggered. So `MM:";d` will capture the semicolon in the second group (greedy), but `MM:";c` will not (since it would fail the lookahead condition if the semicolon had been consumed). Does that match the observed behavior?

Comment: yes that seems to be the case. Is there a way to force it to consume the semi-colon in the 2nd group while keeping it as optional

Comment: You might try (;)?[^c;]

Comment: the problem is that I substituted C for a word in this example, to make it simpler, but that is why I was using negative lookahead

Comment: Ah well... then I need to think about it for a little bit.

Comment: How about the following: `\"(\S\S+)\"(;|)((?!c)|(?!;c))` - this ought to work... it seemed to do it for me. See updated answer.

Comment: it should come as not matched but it is coming up as matched